# Encoding a bcrypt string with mcrypt

Tags: php, encryption, encoding, hash, bcrypt

Using PHP, I've created the following set of functions witch ultimately takes a string (password) and applies a bcrypt encryption to it. Furthermore, it generates a key to use with mcrypt then applies that to the bcrypt string (along with base64 to simplify the string) to then insert into a database for storage.
From this when decoding I decrypt the mcrypt encryption applied to the hash and then use `password_verify()` to then validate it.

However, I am not able to get `password_verify()` to validate the hash if it has been run through the mcrypt process, even though after it has been decoded the two strings (one from the encode function and one from the decode) are IDENTICAL.

The encode function looks like this:

```
function passwordEncode($string) {
    $hash = password_hash($string, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 12]);

    $key = generateKey();

    $encrypt = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key."******", $hash, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));

    return [$encrypt, $key, $hash];
}
```

This would return:

```
[0] ENCRYPT: lTzVGcAY1jkuawebFG/9ZI4O5f/+4hjZHRewstOBAAJwQlYydLJ+B+2QHg9A16qjCUe7FHfTacPzmvH+xnT4rQ==
[1] KEY: 122593420654793b0ee4efc932
[2] HASH: $2y$10$k/4gM1jMIMxnmfBMgrML6enMgqIvnZp2EzPU.G64P3Bb3MDrwJj8e
```

*The HASH index is only for debugging purposes to provide an output hash that has not been run through the mcrypt process*

The decode function looks like this:

```
function passwordDecode($string, $key) {
    $decrypt = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key."******", base64_decode($string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

    return $decrypt;
}
```

This would return:

```
DECRYPT: $2y$10$k/4gM1jMIMxnmfBMgrML6enMgqIvnZp2EzPU.G64P3Bb3MDrwJj8e
```

---

Using the raw hash that hasn't been run through mcrypt returns `Verified`

```
$encode = passwordEncode("password");
if(password_verify("password", $encode[2])) {
    echo 'Verified';
} else {
    echo 'Not verified';
}
```

However using the hash run through mcrypt encryption and decryption returns `Not verified`

```
$encode = passwordEncode("password");
if(password_verify("password", passwordDecode($encode[0], $encode[1]))) {
    echo 'Verified';
} else {
    echo 'Not verified';
}
```

After spending hours essentially grinding my forehead against a cheese grater, I still haven't been able to figure out what mcrypt is doing to the string to unverify it. I've made an attempt at searching for invisible characters (keyword attempt) but other than that I'm out of ideas as to what the cause is.

---

Edit: also, this returns not verified

```
$encode = passwordEncode("password");
if($encode[2]==passwordDecode($encode[0], $encode[1])) {
    echo 'Verified';
} else {
    echo 'Not verified';
}
```

So something's being done to the string...I just don't know what

Comment: Why are you encrypting a one-way hash?

Comment: @HoboSapiens Everything in the database is being encrypted with mcrypt. I would rather not having a bit of mixing and matching of the front end encryption for different columns. I mean I'm aware that I don't need to do mcrypt on bcrypt, but for the sake of consistency I thought why not.

Comment: Fair enough, although if your decryption key is stored on the server the value of the encryption is marginal.

Comment: What about creating an example that we can actually run? You've created some "unbalanced" functions (i.e. the decoding functions do more or less than the encoding functions) that it very hard to see what is actually happening.

Comment: @owlstead From the part where it has the if statement thats the practical part. I actually keep these as functions in the code and execute them when I need to.

Comment: @SteppingHat That's great, but it is impossible *for me* to see where you go wrong, and I'll be darned if I am going to write the business logic around your functions. Especially as that may the place where things go wrong.

Comment: @owlstead I can't see what more code I could add for you, apart form taking all 4 snippets and adding them together as one paragraph that is quite literally all my code.

Comment: Yet, when I tried to run this I found my PHP version to be out of date and `generateKey` missing. That's why you need to generate a piece of code that runs on its own. Next time *listen*.

Comment: @owlstead My apologies. I wasn't meant to include that in the question and replace it with a static string as I wasn't trying to include it as part of the issue because it was unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some stupid reason PHP includes the `\0` valued characters that are used as zero padding by mcrypt in the decrypted plaintext. Even more stupid, those seem to be included in the base64 decoding performed by `password_verify` as well, which make it fail without explicit reason. This kind of stupidity makes PHP one of the worst environments to use for security related functions.

So without further ado, the rewritten functions that perform `rtrim`, in a piece of code that *can* be run on it's own. Requires either PHP 5.5 or [password_compat](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/master/lib/password.php) :

```
<?php

# uncomment for PHP 5.3/5.4
# require "lib/password.php";

function generateKey() {
    $fp = @fopen('/dev/urandom','rb');
    if ($fp !== FALSE) {
        $key = @fread($fp, 16);
        @fclose($fp);
        return $key;
    }
    return null;
}

function hashPassword($password) {
    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 12));
    return $hash;
}

function encryptHash($key, $hash) {
    # encrypt using unsafe ECB mode and without AES
    $encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $hash, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $encoded = base64_encode($encrypted);
    return $encoded;
}

function decryptHash($key, $ciphertext) {
    $decoded = base64_decode($ciphertext);
    $decryptedHash = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $decoded, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    # remove stupid zero padding
    $decryptedHash = rtrim($decryptedHash, "\0");
    return $decryptedHash;
}

$hash = hashPassword("password");

if(password_verify("password", $hash)) {
    echo 'Verified' . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo 'Not verified' . PHP_EOL;
}

$key = generateKey();
$encrypted = encryptHash($key, $hash);
$decrypted = decryptHash($key, $encrypted);

if(password_verify('password', $decrypted)) {
    echo 'Verified' . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo 'Not verified' . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

Comment: Ah I thought it had to do with some stupid invisible character. I do agree with how mediocre PHP can be at times, especially with sensitive and critical functions like this. Thanks heaps for your help!

Comment: Beware that MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 is not AES, it cannot be decrypted by runtimes that don't allow Rijndael with a 256 bit block size. I specifically mentioned this in the sample code of mcrypt_encrypt that I rewrote for PHP.

Comment: I noticed that comment. I'm aware of that already and is making sure that the runtimes that I'm working with allow Rijndael256. I was already using this mode with mcrypt beforehand, but thanks for the reminder :)